# class method using class attribute and subclasse

Tags: python, class, methods, attributes

```
class Choices(object):
        __choices = set(["Boss"])

        @classmethod
        def choices(cls):
            return list(cls.__choices)

class ChoicesA(Choices):
     __choices = set(['A'])

>> ChoicesA.choices()

>> ['Boss']
```

But i wanted `['A']`

Why are the class method not using the class attribute from the subclass?
Is it not a python error? Why python don't use the class method applicated to the real class (the subclass)?

Do you have a solution? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks.I don't want to modifiy the parent attribute, but the child attribute. But i want to define the method once, in the parent.

Comment: I found a solution: `class Choices(object):
        _choices = set(["Boss"])

        @classmethod
        def choices(cls):
            return list(cls._choices)

class ChoicesA(Choices):
    _choices = set(['A'])`

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
class Choices(object):
        choices_ = set(["Boss"])

        @classmethod
        def choices(cls):
            return list(cls.choices_)

class ChoicesA(Choices):
     choices_ = set(['A'])

>> ChoicesA.choices()

>> ['A']
```

Did you notice the change ??

**I just made choices public (Earlier it was private).**

Now here is the explanation:

When we use __choices, before execution python automatically changes the names of private members. So __choices in class A will become _A__choices and __choices in class B will become _B__choices. And both will be accessible from child class. So you code will be converted to :

```
class Choices(object):
        _Choices__choices = set(["Boss"])

        @classmethod
        def choices(cls):
            return list(cls._Choices__choices)

class ChoicesA(Choices):
     _ChoicesA__choices = set(['A'])
```

And you will get ['Boss'] as your result.

And this will be done only to avoid overwriting the private members of parent classes by the child class. Actually in python nothing is private and everything from the parent class will be inherited in child class.

You may try this:

```
print(ChoicesA._ChoicesA__choices)  # ['A']
print(ChoicesA._Choices__choices)   # ['Boss']
```

The concept of name conversion is called mangling.